# cannot getcontext with svelte

Tags: svelte, sapper

I want to make my data globally accessible. From my understanding I can either use Context API or store and as my data is static I thought it was easier to use context API but I can't make it work.

This is my data component :

```
//MyDATA.svelte
<script>
   import { setContext } from "svelte";
   setContext("folioData",42);
</script>
```

This is the component that want to retrieve the data

```
//MyComponent.svelte    
<script>
  import { getContext } from "svelte";
  const folioData = getContext("folioData");
  console.log(folioData); //--------> undefined
</script>
```

I know, it's only the tutorial... The two files are in the same folder. Maybe there is an import problem ? The MyData file is not imported anywhere.

I'm sure this is a noob (which I am) question but I've been struggling for hours on this.

Any hint would be welcome. Thanks a lot !

Comment: What I understood is that context is to communicate with all children components. For a global data in the app, you should use the store : https://svelte.dev/tutorial/readable-stores

Comment: Thanks @JeffProd. What about a context in the App.svelte then ? Stores feel  complicated to me right now for just somme constants. But maybe it's the only way...

Comment: @16ar Why don't you use just a js module? Just simply import it and done. No need to mess with stores just for some constants.

Comment: Hi @Fygo, I managed to use a store eventually but that seems a better idea for my need ! I just never used them so I didn't know this was possible... Maybe if you can put some example in the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a simple constant I would just use a javascript file (or a module, I prefer that one).

Example:
Create a file, e.g. constants.js in your src folder (or any subfolder you want):

```
export default {
  CSS_BASE_PREFIX: 'abc',
  ANIMATION_DURATION: 300
}
```

...and then import it in your component:

```
<script>
  import constants from './constants';

  const basePrefix = constants.CSS_BASE_PREFIX;
  console.log('Anim duration:', constants.ANIM_DURATION);
</script>

<div class="{basePrefix}-my-comp">...</div>
```

It is up to you, what kind of structure you want to give it (export default, named export, etc.) Just a warning: because the imported object is a 'const' but its properties are not, you could actually overwrite them in the above example (why would you do that tho?): `constants.ANIMATION_DURATION = 600; // don't do this`.

...or you could just do this (constants.js):

```
export const CSS_BASE_PREFIX = 'abc';
export const ANIMATION_DURATION = 300;
```

And then in your svelte component:

```
<script>
  import * as constants from './constants';

  const basePrefix = constants.CSS_BASE_PREFIX;
  console.log('Anim duration:', constants.ANIM_DURATION);
</script>
```

You won't be able to reassign it anymore, it will fail at compile time. The choice is yours.